# Numerical aperture of a multimode optical fibre

Tags: optics, refraction, fiber-optics

The refractive indices of the core and cladding of a multimode optical fiber are 1.62 and
1.52 respectively. Calculate its numerical aperture if the optical fiber is placed in (a)
water (b) ice (c) placed in water with the core removed and cladding replaced with ice.
The refractive indices for water and ice are 1.33, 1.31 respectively.

I know numerical aperture = $\sqrt{n_1^2 -n_2^2}$, so, numerical aperture should not depend on the medium in which it is placed in. Please help me to understand the concept for problem,i will solve it.

Or N. A=$n_0 sin{\theta_a}$

Thanks a lot. I have typed question as it was asked just to avoid error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numerical Aperture doesn't depends on the medium it is placed in. Simply use the formula Numerical aperture and proceed, you have the values of refractive index of core and Claddings. You are using right formula.